# Applying linear transformations to equations of curves

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am currently learning linear algebra. I wonder if it possible to use linear transformations to find equations of curves that are translated or rotated. For example how can I use matrices to find an equation of a parabola rotated by 45 degrees clockwise?

Comment: Absolutely. And this is a very important application of linear algebra. Look up rotation matrices.

Comment: I tried it and got (x-y)^2 = sqrt(2)(x+y). Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculus is
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos(-\pi/4)&-\sin(-\pi/4)\\\sin(-\pi/4)&\cos(-\pi/4)
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\x^2\end{array}\right).$$

That is because the matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)
\end{array}\right)$$ rotate the points on the plane by a $\theta$ angle.

Comment: This works for parametric curves. What about implicit curves? (In this case the equations are respectively $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$ and $x^2-y=0$, but in general it's not easy to convert one to the other.)

Comment: Further, this works for every curve parametrically determined : )

Comment: That's what I said. But what about something like $x^5+x^4-2x^2y^2+5y^7=0$?

Comment: Ha! you are funny... well, you can use https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=contour+plot+x%5E5%2Bx%5E4%E2%88%922x%5E2y%5E2%2B5y%5E7%3D0 . and then rotate the whole plane

Answer (score 2):

A linear transformation $L$ sends a point $\vec x$ to $\vec x'=L(\vec x)$. You want to apply this to all points on some curve. (It also works for surfaces etc.)

If you have a parametric equation $\vec x=f(t)$, then you can apply the transformation to the output: $\vec x'=L(\vec x)=L(f(t))$. In other words the new parametric function is $L\circ f$.

If you have an implicit equation $f(\vec x)=0$, then you can apply the inverse transformation to the input: $f(L^{-1}(\vec x'))=f(\vec x)=0$. In other words the new implicit function is $f\circ L^{-1}$.

(The standard parabola has parametric equation $(x_1,x_2)=(t,t^2)$ and implicit equation $x_1^2-x_2=0$.)